# How to create an entry when dealing with Many-to-Many relationships?

Tags: sql, database

I am struggling to understand if I am approaching this scenario correctly:

I have `users` and I have `events`.  A User can belong to many events, and a Event can have many users.  If I create a new Event(id, name, description, date), I also want to store all the Users (let's say there are 5 users) who might be going to this event.

In order to do this, does my transaction have to include both of the following:

1. Insert the new Event(name, description, date) into `events`
2. Insert 5 rows of Event_User(event_id, user_id) into `events_users`

Or, is there another way to do this?

For what its worth, I'm using nodeJS + knex query builder, and I'm able to successfully do the transaction listed above.  It adds the event, and it also adds the n users who might be going to said event to the `events_users` table. However, I'm trying to understand how something like this might be done (without using an ORM) so I would like to know if the approach is at least correct.

Thanks!

Comment: Your approach is correct. For N-to-N relations, the best practice is to keep this info in the separate table (events_users for your example)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest using a third table--say, `event_attendance`--to track which `users` are attending which `events`. You can query the attendance with [joins](http://www.sql-join.com/) as needed. This is a very common practice and is good to be familiar with:

```
-- this query will tell you who is attending what
SELECT usr.username, evt.eventname, evt.eventdate
  FROM event_attendance att
 INNER JOIN events evt
    ON att.eventid=evt.eventid
 INNER JOIN users usr
    ON att.userid=usr.userid
 ORDER BY evt.eventdate ASC;
```

[Here is a sql fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/3e001f/17) demonstrating this. I created very simple tables:

```
CREATE TABLE users (userid int, username varchar);
CREATE TABLE events (eventid int, eventname varchar, eventdate date);
CREATE TABLE event_attendance (eventid int, userid int);
```

Then populated them with data:

```
-- create some users and events
INSERT INTO users VALUES (1, 'Jack');
INSERT INTO users VALUES (2, 'Jill');
INSERT INTO users VALUES (3, 'Anusha');
INSERT INTO users VALUES (4, 'Pierre');

INSERT INTO events VALUES (1, 'A Movie', '2017-11-30');
INSERT INTO events VALUES (2, 'Christmas Dinner', '2017-12-25');
INSERT INTO events VALUES (3, 'Skydiving trip', '2018-05-01');
INSERT INTO events VALUES (4, 'Big Reunion', '2018-06-01');

-- insert some attendance records
INSERT INTO event_attendance VALUES (1, 1);
INSERT INTO event_attendance VALUES (2, 1);
INSERT INTO event_attendance VALUES (2, 2);
INSERT INTO event_attendance VALUES (3, 2);
INSERT INTO event_attendance VALUES (3, 3);
INSERT INTO event_attendance VALUES (4, 1);
INSERT INTO event_attendance VALUES (4, 2);
INSERT INTO event_attendance VALUES (4, 3);
INSERT INTO event_attendance VALUES (4, 4);
```

Given this data, here are the attendance results you'll get from the query above:

```
+----------+------------------+------------+
| username |    eventname     | eventdate  |
+----------+------------------+------------+
| Jack     | A Movie          | 2017-11-30 |
| Jack     | Christmas Dinner | 2017-12-25 |
| Jill     | Christmas Dinner | 2017-12-25 |
| Jill     | Skydiving trip   | 2018-05-01 |
| Anusha   | Skydiving trip   | 2018-05-01 |
| Jill     | Big Reunion      | 2018-06-01 |
| Pierre   | Big Reunion      | 2018-06-01 |
| Anusha   | Big Reunion      | 2018-06-01 |
| Jack     | Big Reunion      | 2018-06-01 |
+----------+------------------+------------+
```

Comment: holy cow.  this is really awesome!  thanks so, SO much

Comment: My pleasure. :) I'm glad it helps.